# C# Microsoft Exchange API Queue Viever

Tags: c#, api, server, exchange-server

I'm searching for some counter from Exchange Service like Transport Details(ex: Total Message Queued for Delivery,Total Messages Submitted etc)

I found a Webservice but it's only for manage Mails,Calendars and other things from outlook

There is a way or API to get counters Exchange Server? using API, EWS ,or something

I have only authentication code right now

```
 ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback =
        delegate (Object obj, X509Certificate certificate, X509Chain chain, SslPolicyErrors errors)
        {
            return true;
        };
        ExchangeService service = new ExchangeService(ExchangeVersion.Exchange2013);


        service.Credentials = new WebCredentials("mail", "Pass");
        service.UseDefaultCredentials = true;
```

Answer (score 1):

To monitor Exchange Server performance you can use Performance Counters: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn904093(v=exchg.150).aspx. Client Access Server Counters display information about client connections (ActiveSync, OWA, EWS). You can collect Performance Counters via Performance Monitor or Powershell.